# JavaScript regexp: Delete line with string occurrence and following two lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say there's a textarea text with following content:

```
On date at 3:16 PM, Sir Voldemort wrote:

> Sweet Harry!
> Let's see what's gonna happen.
>
>
> On date at 3:11 PM, wrote:
>
>> Awesome!
>>
>>
>> --
>> Random: string or sentence here, it doesn't matter
>> Another random line with e.g. a URL: http://www.jkrowling.com/
>>
>
>
>
> --
> **********************************************
>   ABCABCCAB
> **********************************************
>

Quote
“Efe iska?” 

--
Random2-1
Random2-2

**********************************************
  ABCABCABC
**********************************************
```

Now if there occurs a line with just two dashes `--` (and none, one or more `>` in front) in it, this line and the following two lines should get deleted.

Like that:

```
On date at 3:16 PM, Sir Voldemort wrote:

> Sweet Harry!
> Let's see what's gonna happen.
>
>
> On date at 3:11 PM, wrote:
>
>> Awesome!
>>
>>
>>
>
>
>
> **********************************************
>

Quote
“Efe iska?” 


**********************************************
  ABCABCABC
**********************************************
```

I already started with the following code to detect the previous line of `--` to start a another `substr` but there is more sure a way more simple regexp solution for it?

```
var msg = document.getElementById('msg'); // wrapped textarea around the text with ID msg
msg.value = msg.value.substr(0, msg.value.substr(0, msg.value.match('--\n').index).lastIndexOf('\n'))
```

Comment: Why are not the lines `> --`, `> *************` and `> ABCABCCAB` being deleted? They follow the pattern you indicate.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right, I forgot to remove them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
str.replace(/\n>*\s*--\n.*\n.*/g, '')
```

Results in:

```
On date at 3:16 PM, Sir Voldemort wrote:

> Sweet Harry!
> Let's see what's gonna happen.
>
>
> On date at 3:11 PM, wrote:
>
>> Awesome!
>>
>>
>>
>
>
>
> **********************************************
>

Quote
“Efe iska?” 

**********************************************
  ABCABCABC
**********************************************
```